# Animation not showing - why?

Tags: android

I am new and studying online . This is my first animation study at Android. The problem is that when I choose the answer my Card View animation is suppose to show immediately. But it didn't show as soon as I click . But I found out that after I click the button, I need to press Home button and resume it from the background apps to start the animation.The animation starts only after I do this process. Toast is showing without a problem. After I choose the answer I always need to do like that to show my animation. The app is about True or false.
Also the coding is exactly the same as my online tutorial. maybe my phone problem ?? I am using Samsung S 7 edge.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView QuestionTextView,QcountTextView;
    private Button Tbutton,Fbutton;
    private ImageButton prev,next;
    private int count = 0;
    private CardView cardView;
    private Animation shake;
    public Questions Qarray[] = new Questions[]{
            new Questions(R.string.Q1, true),
            new Questions(R.string.Q2, false),
            new Questions(R.string.Q3, true),
            new Questions(R.string.Q4, true),
            new Questions(R.string.Q5, false),
            new Questions(R.string.Q6, true),
            new Questions(R.string.Q7, false)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Tbutton = findViewById(R.id.tb);
        Fbutton = findViewById(R.id.fb);
        QuestionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questionshow);
        QcountTextView = findViewById(R.id.Qcount);
        next = findViewById(R.id.nb);
        prev = findViewById(R.id.pb);
        cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.shakeanimation);

        Tbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Fbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);

        QuestionTextView.setText(Qarray[count].question);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.tb:
                giveanswer(true);
                pagechange();
                break;
            case R.id.fb:
                giveanswer(false);
                pagechange();
                break;
            case R.id.pb:
                if(count != 0) {
                    count = (count - 1);
                    pagechange();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nb:
                count = (count + 1) % Qarray.length;
                pagechange();
                break;

        }
    }

    private void pagechange() {
        QuestionTextView.setText(Qarray[count].getQuestion());
        QcountTextView.setText((count+1) + " out of " + Qarray.length);
    }

    private void giveanswer(boolean b) {
        boolean correctanswer = Qarray[count].ans;
        if(b == correctanswer){
            fadeView();
            Toast.makeText(this,R.string.yes,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            ShakeAnimation();
            Toast.makeText(this,R.string.no,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private  void fadeView(){
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(350);
        alphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
        alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        cardView.setAnimation(alphaAnimation);

        alphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new 
    Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(41,226,205));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ShakeAnimation(){
        cardView.setAnimation(shake);
        shake.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(41,226,205));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I expect the animation show as soon as I choose the answer.

Comment: you forgot to call start

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `alphaAnimation.start();` or `shake.start();` just having animation listeners is not gonna start your animation when you want it to start.

try adding these lines exactly where you want the animations to run.

For Example:

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(350);
    alphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
    alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    cardView.setAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    alphaAnimation.start();
```

Also `setAnimation` should to be used with xml Animations if I'm not mistaking

Comment: thanks very much Shahin. I changed it to cardView.startAnimation(shake); It worked.